# How to access this object? it keeps returning a string of undefined

Tags: javascript

In this kata you are required to, given a string, replace every letter with its position in the alphabet.

If anything in the text isn't a letter, ignore it and don't return it.

"a" = 1, "b" = 2, etc.

Example

```
alphabet_position("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock.")
```

Should return `"20 8 5 19 21 14 19 5 20 19 5 20 19 1 20 20 23 5 12 22 5 15 3 12 15 3 11"` (as a string)

How to access this object? it keeps returning a string of undefined.

```js
function alphabetPosition(text) {
  var alphabet = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4,
    e: 5,
    f: 6,
    g: 7,
    h: 8,
    i: 9,
    j: 10,
    k: 11,
    l: 12,
    m: 13,
    n: 14,
    o: 15,
    p: 16,
    q: 17,
    r: 18,
    s: 19,
    t: 20,
    u: 21,
    v: 22,
    w: 23,
    x: 24,
    y: 25,
    z: 26
  }
  var number = 0;
  var string = "";
  var letter = "";

  for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    letter = text.charAt(i);
    number = alphabet.letter;
    string += number + " ";

  }
  return string;
}

var res = alphabetPosition("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock.");

console.log(res, res === "20 8 5 19 21 14 19 5 20 19 5 20 19 1 20 20 23 5 12 22 5 15 3 12 15 3 11");
```

Comment: `number = alphabet[letter]` What you have is looking up the value at the literal key `"letter"`, which doesn't exist - hence `undefined`

Comment: https://repl.it/@johntduong/Code-Wars-Replace-With-Alphabet-Position

Comment: you may also want to consider what happens when you have an uppercase letter in your string (hint: convert to lowercase)

Answer (score 1):

Try following

- `alphabet.letter` should be `alphabet[letter.toLowerCase()]` - for ignore case
- For spaces and other characters, place a check for `if(number)`

```js
function alphabetPosition(text) {
    var alphabet = {a: 1,b: 2,c: 3,d: 4,e: 5,f: 6,g: 7,h: 8,i: 9,j: 10,k: 11,l: 12,m: 13,n: 14,o: 15,p: 16,q: 17,r: 18,s: 19,t: 20,u: 21,v: 22,w: 23,x: 24,y: 25,z: 26};
    var number = 0;
    var string = "";
    var letter ="";

    for (i=0; i<text.length; i++) {
      letter = text.charAt(i);
      number = alphabet[letter.toLowerCase()];
      if(number) string += number + " "; 

    }
    return string;
}
console.log(alphabetPosition("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock."));
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistakes in your code. Please follow below steps in order to solve the problem.

- Use bracket notation for accessing *dynamically* properties.
- Use `toLowerCase()` method in order to convert `upper case` letters also.
- Treat the special *space* case, because there is not converting rule for it.

```js
function alphabetPosition(text) {
var alphabet ={
a: 1,
b: 2,
c: 3,
d: 4,
e: 5,
f: 6,
g: 7,
h: 8,
i: 9,
j: 10,
k: 11,
l: 12,
m: 13,
n: 14,
o: 15,
p: 16,
q: 17,
r: 18,
s: 19,
t: 20,
u: 21,
v: 22,
w: 23,
x: 24,
y: 25,
z: 26
}
var number = 0;
var string = "";
var letter ="";

for (i=0; i< text.length; i++) {
  letter = text.charAt(i).toLowerCase();
  number = alphabet[letter] || '';
  string += number + " "; 

}
  return string;
}

console.log(alphabetPosition("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock."))
```

Also, you can simplify your method by using `map` method.

```
return text.split('').map(c => alphabet[c.toLowerCase()] || '').join(' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

You had issue with your code: when storing object property name in a variable, you should use `[]` notation to access property value. in your example you had `alphabet.letter` which should have been `alphabet[letter]`

```js
function alphabetPosition(text) {
  var alphabet = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4,
    e: 5,
    f: 6,
    g: 7,
    h: 8,
    i: 9,
    j: 10,
    k: 11,
    l: 12,
    m: 13,
    n: 14,
    o: 15,
    p: 16,
    q: 17,
    r: 18,
    s: 19,
    t: 20,
    u: 21,
    v: 22,
    w: 23,
    x: 24,
    y: 25,
    z: 26
  }
  var number = 0;
  var string = "";
  var letter = "";

  for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    letter = text.charAt(i).toLowerCase();
    number = alphabet[letter];
    if (typeof number !== 'undefined') {
       string += number + " ";
    }
    
  }
  return string.trim();
}

var res = alphabetPosition("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock.");

console.log(res, res === "20 8 5 19 21 14 19 5 20 19 5 20 19 1 20 20 23 5 12 22 5 15 3 12 15 3 11");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can skip that object altogether if you consider that the index of each letter is its ascii/utf-16 code minus 97 (the ascii code of the letter 'a') plus 1 (because your letters start at 1 instead of 0). So you can solve it like this:

```js
function alphabetPosition(text) {
  var str = "";
  for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    var c = text.charAt(i).toLowerCase();
    var code = c.charCodeAt(0);
    if (code >= 97 && code <= 122) str += ((code - 97 + 1) + " ")
  }
  return str;
}

console.log(alphabetPosition("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock."));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ASCII codes, your code will not required alphabet array

```js
var str = "The sunset sets at twelve o' clock.";

function CharToAsciiConversion(str){
  var result = "";
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  var ascii = str.charCodeAt(i) - 96;
  if(ascii > 0 && ascii < 26)
     result += ascii + " ";
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(CharToAsciiConversion(str));
```